# Unable to Open Database (sqlite using c in swift)

Tags: c, swift, database, sqlite

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true).first!
    let db = "\(path)/ishop.sqlite3"

    let name: [CChar]? = db.cString(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
    getInput(UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>(mutating: name!))

}
```

int getInput(char dbname[]) 
{

```
sqlite3 *db;
sqlite3_stmt *res;

int rc = sqlite3_open_v2("dbname", &db, SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE | SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE | SQLITE_OPEN_URI |SQLITE_OPEN_MAIN_DB , NULL);

if (rc != SQLITE_OK) {


    fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open database: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
    sqlite3_close(db);

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: use this library for sqlite https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but i need to do it using C API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sqlite3_open_v2("dbname",
```

The first parameter is a string, consisting of the six letters `dbname`.

If you want to use the `dbname` parameter, don't enclose it in quotes.